# Part of Images not loading after deploying to GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, typescript, github

I have a site that I deployed to GitHub Pages. In this site there are several pictures, one background image and 5 images, of which one will be shown randomly in a modal on page load.

The Background image is loading fine, but all of the others throw an 404 in the browser after deployment to GitHub Pages - on my localhost it works fine.

I deployed the app using following command:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href="url to my repo"
```

and

```
npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=dist/lo-l5v5-generator/
```

One thing that stood out to me, even though all images are stored in my assets folder, in the list folder - which is used to deploy it to GitHub iirc - the background image is present outside the assets folder with random numbers attached to the name - and in the browser I can see that it is in fact this picture that is loaded - not the one in the assets folder.

All the other pictures however stay in the assets folder.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: In general, the scr of an image is like `assets/....`  or `./assets/...`. Check anyway where are yours images really. In navigator (using F12) change the path of  one img until you reach it